# How to determine Grass (i.atcorr) tool control file's "visibility for the aerosol model [km]" value

Tags: grass-gis, visibility, atmospheric-correction

In Grass, the Atmospheric Correction tool (i.atcorr) reference do not provide information with regards to the parameter "visibility for the aerosol model [km]"stated in the control file.I have searched exhaustively online. But could not find the data source or methodology to generate it. Does it mean Vertical visibility or viewing height? As far I can understand, the parameter should be independent of the visibility map (because visibility map raster cell value reflects count # of other cells it can see). I have already explored the Aeronet website but could not find any Visibility (km) data. Please let us know the data source (if there is any) and calculation methodology for "visibility for the aerosol model [km]" preferably, in layman's term.

Update: The following paper indicates, Visibility (km) refers to horizontal visibility measured at airports. I'll look further to find any free source where historical record of such data is available. Any suggestion is welcome.

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjV_ZOgkMLJAhVCOBQKHUkVDiEQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rtwilson.com%2Facademic%2FWilsonMiltonNield_2015_VisAOT.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGxH9CL0U8fDQJawtA8aazVpy4KJg